# Homeomorphism with a bouquet of two circles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I understand why removing two points from $\mathbb R^2$ gives a surface that is homeomorphic to a bouquet of two circles. But can someone please write this homeomorphism?

Comment: It's not homeomorphic, it's homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Just do it for one circle..

Comment: @user99680: are you implying that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one point removed is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: @user99680 $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is not at all homeomorphic to a circle, if that's what you were implying at first. That's also only a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @JustinCampbell: No, I had a dyslexia-type moment; I meant to say that $\mathbb R^2 \cup $ {$pt$} is homeomorphic to $ S^2$ Still, the cutset argument shows neither is a homeomorphism. I'm having my doppio shot, which should stop my mistakes --at least for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it has been remarked in the comments, $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{p,q\}$ is **not** homeomorphic to a bouquet of two circles! However there is a **deformation retraction** of that space to a subspace homeomorphic to the bouquet of two circles, in particular they have the same **homotopy type**. The deformation retraction can be written down explicitely, but it is a bit messy and not really enlightening. If you want it, write a comment and I will write it down.

---

Ok, I will explain how I would construct a deformation retraction from $X=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{-1,1\}$ to a subspace $Y\subset X$ homeomorphic to $S^1\vee S^1$. Notice that the retraction induced this way is a homotopy equivalence between the two spaces (with inverse the inclusion $Y\to X$).

Let $Z$ be the union of the circle of radius $2$ centered in $0$ with the vertical segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$. We define a deformation retraction $F:[0,1]\times X\to X$ by:
$$F(t,x)=\cases{\left(\frac{t}{\|x\|}+(1-t)\right)x & if $\|x\|\ge2$\\
tz(x)+(1-t)x&else}$$
where $z(x)$ is $x$ if $x_1=0$, and the intersection which is closest to $x$ of the straight  line passing through $x$ and the closest point to $x$ between $(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ (you can write this down explicitly, but you have to separate a couple more cases). This map deforms $X$ to $Z$ keeping $Z$ fixed.

Next define $G:[0,1]\times Z\to X$ by $G(t,x)=ty(x)+(1-t)x$, where $y(t)$ is the point of $Y$ which is closest to $x$ along the vertical line passing through $x$ (again, you can write this down easily if you want). This maps deforms the space $Z$ to $Y$.

The map $H:[0,1]\times X\to X$ defined by:
$$H(x,t)=\cases{F(2t,x)&if $t\le1$\\G(2t-1,F(1,x))&if $t\ge1$}$$
is the desired deformation retraction.

Comment: I mean a homotopy, not a homeomorphism. My mistake.
I know, that this retraction is a bit messy and I think, it's possible to write somehow cleverly?

Comment: @user128873 I wrote down how I would construct the deformation retraction. I am not aware of any elegant way to do it.